# Can Tyrell Wellick fire people on the spot?

Tags: realism, mr-robot

In the TV show, *Mr. Robot*, Tyrell Wellick shouts at two of his managers "You are fired!" when they make jokes about "Someone was willing to go gay in order to get some inside information." That "someone" is actually Tyrell Wellick.

My question is:

- Can Tyrell Wellick fire people on the spot?

Comment: It's not a sufficiently large edit for me to be able to submit it as an edit suggestion (and there's not really anything else that needs to be changed), but the bulletpoint formatting being used here is inappropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many companies in the United States practice what's known as "at-will" employment. It basically means that you can be fired at any time, for any reason, without any notice or warning. So yes, assuming his company practices at-will employment, he can absolutely fire people on the spot like that.